# How to Process textbox value to variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I want to be able to type something into a textbox and then get an `alert` saying what I typed. Easy Right? I tried using `getElementbyId` and made some variables to accomodate with this, but it turns out it gives undefined.
This is the code:

```
    <input type="submit" name="button" style="position: absolute; top: 283.5px; left: 45%; width: 142px; height: 40px; background-color:lime; border-color:forestgreen; font-weight:700; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif" value="CLICK ME"/>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 283.5px; left: 23%; width: 142px; height: 40px; background-color:lime; border-color:forestgreen;">
        <input type="text" name="linksubmit" id="linksubmit" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; width:138px" />
    </div>
    <script>
        var linksubmit = document.getElementById("linksubmit").value 
        function Button() {
            alert(linksubmit)
        }
    </script>
```

---

If any of you have a valid reason why this could not be working, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is undefined, and where are you calling function Button?

Comment: in this example i forgot to do onclick="button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const theThing = document.getElementById('testerooni');
showMe = () => { alert(theThing.value) };
```

```html
<input id="testerooni" type="text">
<button onclick="showMe()">SHOW ME</button>
```

Comment: Looks like I was a lil late hitting the submit button, kshetline is the same thing minus es6 syntax. Upvoting his for answering speed :D

Comment: Thank You So Much Chris You Are A Hero. You deserve an upvote too!

Answer (score 2):

The value is only being captured once, before your function is called. You need something more like:

```
        var linksubmit = document.getElementById("linksubmit"); 
        function Button() {
            // Get the value each time the button is pressed, instead of reporting
            // an old, stale value (probably empty string/null/undefined.)
            alert(linksubmit.value);
        }
```